# In the following example from .Net Maui XAML 2009, why does the RelativeSource fail to get the Picker?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, findancestor, xaml-2009

```xml
<Picker>
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <c:List x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <x:String>apple</x:String>
            <x:String>orange</x:String>
        </c:List>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
    <Picker.SelectedItem>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:SampleConverter SampleBindable="{Binding ItemsSource, Source={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Picker}}}" />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Picker.SelectedItem>
</Picker>
```

My understanding was that I could get the Picker control by specifying "Picker" in the AncestorType of FindAncestor, but this does not seem to be the case.
Can anyone explain why?

If I give the Picker a name and change the RelativeSource to x:Reference as shown below, I can get it successfully (the "SampleBindable" property reflects the contents of the ItemsSource of the Picker).

```xml
<Picker x:Name="pick">
```

```xml
<local:SampleConverter SampleBindable="{Binding ItemsSource, Source={x:Reference pick}}" />
```

but, It seems somewhat redundant to name the control every time just for these bindings...
does anyone know of a way to avoid having to name the Picker control?

Answer (score 0):

`Source` is typically used for statically addressing a source located elsewhere. If you want to climb the tree to find a relative parent, you can use `RelativeSource` instead.  Try this:

```xml
<local:SampleConverter SampleBindable="{Binding ItemsSource, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Picker}}}" />
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.
This problem occurs in MAUI, not WPF, and in MAUI, relative binding is set for the ```Source``` property. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0#bind-to-an-ancestor)
Please try again with the MAUI project.

Comment: I tried the code presented in WPF as well, but it still did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you were not binding to an ancestor. The official document said:

> The FindAncestor and FindAncestorBindingContext relative binding modes are used to bind to parent elements, of a certain type, in the visual tree

The picker is not a parent element. And I can seem only one picker in the xaml. It seems be binding to self. So you can try:

```
<local:SampleConverter SampleBindable="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ItemsSource />
```

Comment: The code you presented tries to bind ```SampleConverter.ItemsSource```, not ```Picker.ItemsSource```.
Have you actually checked the behavior of that code?
It did not work as intended, at least in my environment.

Comment: So binding to an ancestor and binding to setl both work in this contidtion. Because there is no parent element.